# Apex Test Failures when trying to deploy

Tags: apex, deployment

I'm getting a "Apex Test Failures" when trying to validate my Change Sets before I deploy.

**Failure Message:**
[image]

**All the Components:**
[image]

I'm not sure why I'm getting these error messages, because I don't have `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION` in my Apex code I'm trying to deploy.

**Apex Code:**

```
/* 
Date: 4/25/2023
---------------
Updated Since: 4/25/2023
*/

public with sharing class QueryData {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunityList() {
    
        List<Opportunity> OppList = new List<Opportunity>();
        OppList = [SELECT Id, Service_City__c, Service_State__c, Service_Street__c, Development_Rep__c, StageName, Name, Project_Type__c, Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c FROM Opportunity ];
    
        return OppList;
    
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have that code in this class, but you do in the `csvDownloadTest` and `■■■■■■■■■■cesControllerTest`. You'll need to fix those unit test classes and deploy them together with your changes. A production deployment must always meet 75% coverage and have 0 errors. If this code isn't local to your own Sandbox, you'll need to somehow deploy the code from production to your Sandbox, perhaps by using a Change Set or SFDX. Also, this error can be raised by validation rules as well, so make sure you check to see if you need to modify or copy any validation rules. There may be other related metadata that you need to include as well, such as the Utility Program object (I'm guessing) and/or fields.

Comment: So I ran the local test, and I am still getting the same errors. I looked into the Apex class `csvDownloadTest` and `■■■■■■■■■■cesControllerTest` and didn't see any variable called `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION`. I'm lost because I didn't make any changes to these Apex files I only created one which is `QueryData`. What else should I look into?

Comment: @Pinto `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION` is the exception raised when you violate a validation rule or use `addError` in a trigger. Try Setup | Object Manager | Opportunities | Validation Rules. If you don't find it there, open the Salesforce Developer Console (Gear icon, Developer Console), and then Edit | Search In Files..., looking for the `addError` method.

Comment: I found that the two methods with the error on line 14 & 19 is: `insert Opp;`, I don't know why its  violating the validation rule. Also, for the Utility Program object I never called it in my Apex code, but not sure if I should look into that?

Comment: @Pinto You do need to create a record and populate the relevant opportunity field before trying to insert the opportunity.

Comment: Ok and should I do this for just the **Utility Program** like: `Opp.Utility_Program__c='Small Business';` or should I do this to all opportunity field that I'm calling in my Apex code that isn't recorded in the two methods?

Comment: @Pinto What's the field definition for utility program? What data type is it?

Comment: Its a Picklist with strings, such as "Small Business"

Comment: @Pinto Then yes, you only need to change the ones that fail. Make sure you go to Setup | Custom Code | Apex Test Execution to run your tests before deploying. You may have further methods that also need to be updated.

Comment: Its worked: **Validate: Succeeded**, Thank you!